# req.body not populating with form data

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

The following files are my attempt at submitting a POST request to my nodejs (express) server.  The req.body does not populate any sort of data from my form.  I have done many searches and found that many of the solutions out there for this particular problem include moving bodyparser before my routes and making sure to include a name in the form fields.
Any help is appreciated.

**app.js**

```
[variables]
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(validator({errorFormatter: -----}));
[other middleware]
require('./passport')(app, passport);
require('./routes')(app, passport);
[start server]
```

**index.jade**

```
block content
h1= title
p Please register below
.error-messages
    ul.errors
        if errors
            each error, i in errors
                li.alert.alert-danger #{error.msg}
form(method='post', action='/signup', enctype='multipart/form-data')
    .form-group
        label Name
        input.form-control(type='text', name='name', placeholder='Enter name')
    .form-group
        label Email
        input.form-control(type='email', name='email', placeholder='Enter email')
    .form-group
        label Username
        input.form-control(type='text', name='username', placeholder='Enter a username')
    .form-group
        label Password
        input.form-control(type='password', name='password')
    .form-group
        label Confirm Password
        input.form-control(type='password', name='passwordConfirm')
    input.btn.btn-primary.pull-right(type='submit', name='submit', value='Sign Up')
```

**index.js** (called from an app.post('/signup', ...)

```
var name = req.body.name,
    email = req.body.email,
    username = req.body.username,
    password = req.body.password,
    passwordConfirm = req.body.passwordConfirm;

name = 'meg';

console.log('name: ' + req.body.name);
console.log('email: ' + req.body.email);
console.log('name2: ' + name);
console.log(req.body);
console.log(req.headers);
console.log(req.is('json'));
```

**console.log**

```
name: undefined
email: undefined
name2: meg
{}
 { host: 'xx.xx.xx.xxx:xx',
 connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '623',
  'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
   accept: 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
  origin: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36      (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.152 Safari/537.36 OPR/29.0.1795.60',
   'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----     WebKitFormBoundaryYJyUQjMbfAn9Cr64',
  dnt: '1',
  referer: 'http://xx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxx/signup',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, lzma',
  'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
  cookie: 'connect.sid=s%3Au9o1F_i22gHj0ZCqpHQiKWDLBGOVU1MJ.6DdtQAqbR6sriI8zF3AjQy6y1TDMD93TMGI7fRIJ5mM' }
 false
```

Answer (score 6):

You're using the wrong enctype for the form, express by default does not support multipart ( which is used for file uploads ), you need to use x-www-form-urlencoded.

```
form(method='post', action='/signup', enctype='application/x-www-form-urlencoded')
```

Comment: Thanks.  This is exactly the change I needed to make to populate the req  data correctly.

Answer (score 5):

You're sending a `multipart/form-data` request but you're not using a `multipart/form-data`-compatible body parsing middleware. Some example middleware modules that do handle that format are [`multer`](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) and [`multiparty`](https://github.com/andrewrk/node-multiparty)/[`formidable`](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable).

Comment: Thank you.  This, in addition to mfreitas answer, helps explain everything.