# 'req.body.username' and 'req.body.password' are undefined

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, body-parser

I am creating login-register system in my project, actually I made it in many of my previous projects but this time I am getting an error, for which I've seen many posts related to this but none of them worked for me.

This is my code:

**app.js**

```
const express= require('express');
const mongoose= require('mongoose');
const bodyParser= require('body-parser');
const exphbs= require('express-handlebars');
const path= require('path');
const methodOverride= require('method-override');
const session= require('express-session');
const flash= require('connect-flash');


const app= express();
const port= process.env.PORT || 8000;

mongoose.Promise= global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI || 
'mongodb://localhost:27017/chat',{ useNewUrlParser: true });
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

//body-parser
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

//View engine
app.engine('.hbs', exphbs({extname: '.hbs'}));
app.set('view engine', '.hbs');

//Load Routes
const index= require('./routes/index');

//Use routes
app.use('/',index);

app.listen(port,()=> {
    console.log(`Started on port ${port}`);
})
```

**routes.index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt= require('bcryptjs');
const {User}= require('../models/User'); 


router.all('/*',(req,res,next)=> {
    req.app.locals.layout= 'layout';
    next();
})

router.get('/login',(req,res,next)=> {

    res.render('routes_UI/login');
})

router.get('/signup',(req,res,next)=> {

    res.render('routes_UI/signup');
})


router.post('/signup',(req,res)=> {

    let errors=[];

    if(req.body.password!==req.body.confirmPassword){
        errors.push({message:'Passwords do not match'});
    }

    if(errors.length>0){
        res.render('routes_UI/signup',{errors});
    }else{

        User.findOne({ username: req.body.username}).then((user)=> {
            if(user){
               req.flash('error_message',`A user with this username already exists`);
               res.redirect('/signup');
            }else{
                    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) {
                    bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, function(err, hash) {

                        const user= new User({
                                username:req.body.username,
                                password:hash,
                            });

                        user.save().then(()=> {
                            req.flash('success_message',`You have 
registered successfully, please login`);
                            res.redirect('/login');
                        });                 
                     });
                  });
            }
        })   
    }   
})

module.exports = router;
```

**routes_UI.signup.hbs** in views folder

```
<div class="card card-register mx-auto mt-5">
    <div class="card-header">Register an Account</div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <form action="/signup" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="username">Username</label>
                <input name="username" class="form-control" id="username" type="text" aria-describedby="username" placeholder="Enter username">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                <input name="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" type="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="exampleConfirmPassword">Confirm password</label>
                <input name="confirmPassword" class="form-control" id="exampleConfirmPassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm password">
            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
        </form>
        <div class="text-center">
            <a class="d-block small mt-3" href="/login">Login Page</a>
            <a class="d-block small" href="/">Home Page?</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Error that I obtained is-**

```
(node:2468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: users 
validation failed: username: Path `username` is required., password: Path 
`password` is required.

at new ValidationError (C:\Users\DEEPAK\chat-app- 
1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\error\validation.js:30:11)

at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\DEEPAK\chat-app- 
1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2064:32)

at p.doValidate.skipSchemaValidators (C:\Users\DEEPAK\chat-app- 
1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1927:17)

at C:\Users\DEEPAK\chat-app-1\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schematype.js:896:9
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)
(node:2468) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. 
This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function 
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with 
.catch(). (rejection id: 1)

(node:2468) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are 
deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will 
 terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**User model**

```
const mongoose= require('mongoose');

const UserSchema= new mongoose.Schema({

    username:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    password:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
const User= mongoose.model('users', UserSchema);

module.exports={User};
```

**Thanks in advance**

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue?

Comment: No, it is giving the same error.

Comment: Please post your mongoose model for users

Comment: When I set required:false for both username and password in User model, a document get saved in database without username and password.

Comment: I added user model in question just now.

Comment: Try to run it with everything commented out, except `console.log(req.body.username)`

Comment: I did that, it was undefined.

Comment: This is weird. At this point, I'd check the api using Postman instead of handlebars. Then at least you know whether handlebar is sending the fields or not

Comment: api is working correctly, I am sending {"username": "abcd", "password": "123456"} as body and got 'abcd' as req.body.username .

Comment: can you tell me what should I do now, I am very confused why it is happening.

Comment: Googling throws up questions like [handlebars form submit does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37840611/handlebars-form-submit-does-not-work) but don't if these are relevant to your issue

Comment: I used a simple form for signup and it worked, then I found that this was the actual problem... https://stackoverflow.com/q/30651484/9854977, I removed enctype='multipart/form-data' and it worked.

Comment: Thank you for your support Sir, I am feeling relaxed now.

Comment: I'm flagging at duplicate so it will be easier for other users to find the cause of this error. Nice that you've resolved it

Comment: @DeepakKumrawat enctype='multipart/form-data' must only be used when you have some file uploads in your form... refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean

Answer (score 3):

```
//body-parser
app.use(function(req, res, next) 
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
```

The above first line of code is incomplete and unnecessary. To correctly initialize body parser you can simply do the following as pointed out in the [documentation](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#expressconnect-top-level-generic).

```
// parse application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: I didn't used that first line, it was by mistake I think..sorry for that. I edited the question now.

Comment: I am very confused why it is happening, even though I have done this simple thing many times in my previous projects.

Comment: `app.use(bodyParser.json())` worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the main body-parser directive:

```
app.use(bodyParser.json())
```

Comment: I used that, it was my mistake..sorry for that.I edited the question now.

Comment: worked for me `app.use(bodyParser.json())`